# How to write in a specific spot in TableView with JavaFX

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, fxml

I am in the process of self-training on the subject of graphic JavaFX

My goal is to be able to place an X in the corresponding box

[image]

I found several tutorials that explain how to write a partial or full row but only one field and depending on the column / row value ... I can't do it, I need help from the community to m 'open my eyes, so run my hoop lol

Thx in advance

Have a nice day/evening/night/morning

Comment: Maybe a [`GridPane`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) would be better suited to your purpose than a TableView.

Comment: For a TableView, you don't update cells in the tableview directly, instead, you modify records in the list which backs the tableview, and those records need to be composed of listenable properties if you want to have updates on those properties trigger updates to the view.  Study up on [cell factories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72437983/why-should-i-avoid-using-propertyvaluefactory-in-javafx) if you want to go this route.  You might also want to look at [extractors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31687642/callback-and-extractors-for-javafx-observablelist).

Comment: Thx @jewelsea :) I will read about GridPane

Answer (score 0):

With GridPane, i found what i probably need :)

```
@FXML
    protected void shootOnGrid(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        if (column.getText().isEmpty() || line.getText().isEmpty() ){
            resultShoot.setText("There is some information missing");
        } else {
            resultShoot.setText(column.getText()+line.getText());
            grid.add(new Text(line.getText()), 0,0);

        }
    }
```

Now, i need to work with thoses property :)
If i can name the Colomn and row...etc

[image]