# How do I make Togglebutton work properly inside tableView column?

Tags: javafx

I want to make my Togglebutons column work properly inside my TableView. When I press toggle button nothing happens. How to repair this? I didn't change anything in my "Medicaments.java" model. It looks like you see below:

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Medicaments, Void> editRow;
```

My model:

```
     public Medicaments(int idNumber, String LOTNumber, String medName, String dateExpiry, int quantity, String unit,String timeLeft) {
    this.idNumber = idNumber;
    this.LOTNumber = LOTNumber;
    this.medName = medName;
    this.dateExpiry = dateExpiry;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.unit = unit;
    this.timeLeft = timeLeft;
}
```

Togglebutton column:

```
 private void AddEditButton() {
    TableColumn<Medicaments, Void> colBtn = new TableColumn("");

    Callback<TableColumn<Medicaments, Void>, TableCell<Medicaments, Void>> cellFactory = new 
     Callback<TableColumn<Medicaments, Void>, TableCell<Medicaments, Void>>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell<Medicaments, Void> call(final TableColumn<Medicaments, Void> param) 
          {
            final TableCell<Medicaments, Void> cell = new TableCell<Medicaments, Void>() {
                private final ToggleButton toggleButton = new ToggleButton("Edit");
                {
                    /**/

                    toggleButton.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event -> {
                        event.consume();
                        toggleButton.selectedProperty().addListener((observable,oldValue, 
                newValue) -> {
                            if(newValue){
                                toggleButton.setText("Save");
                            } else {
                                toggleButton.setText("Edit");
                            }
                        });

                    });
                    /*btn.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event ->{
                        event.consume();
                        Medicaments data = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
                        System.out.println("selectedData: " + data);

                    });*/

                }
                @Override
                public void updateItem(Void item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else {
                        setGraphic(toggleButton);
                    }
                }
            };
            return cell;
        }
    };
    editRow.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to provide a [mcve] to get debugging help.  Also better explain what you are trying to do. What is the purpose of the toggle buttons in the column? What should happen when they are pressed (or unpressed)?  Are the toggle buttons supposed to part of a toggle group?  It is hard to explain how to make something work properly when you don't know what it is supposed to do.

Comment: FOr example when togglebutonn is selected -> setText(save) and unselected -> setText(Edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Example output

[image: example]

#### Description of approach

The implementation here adds this property to the model class (`Person`) backing the TableView item list:

```
private final BooleanProperty toggleState;
```

The property is used to maintain the state of the toggle for the item within the model.  In a real implementation, you can call the property something that would be meaningful within your application domain.

The toggle property of the model is initialized in the constructor for the model:

```
this.toggleState = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
```

A new column is defined to hold the toggle button.  Cell value and cell factories are defined for the column:

```
TableColumn<Person, Person> toggleColumn = new TableColumn<>("Toggle");
toggleColumn.setCellValueFactory(item -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(item.getValue()));
toggleColumn.setCellFactory(p -> new ToggleTableCell());
```

In the new `ToggleTableCell` class, we define the toggle button and a link to the property in the model class that the toggle button value is bound to:

```
private final ToggleButton toggleButton = new ToggleButton();
private BooleanProperty boundProperty;
```

The `updateItem` method of the `ToggleButtonCell` maintains a bi-directional binding between the value property of the toggle button and the property representing the model state in the currently displayed model item (the `toggleState` property).  That way, if the button is toggled or the model data is updated independently through the model API, both the internal state of the toggle button and the internal state of the model object are kept in sync, with the correct visuals for the state reflected in the UI.

The `boundProperty` field of the `ToggleTableCell` is used so that when the item in a table row is updated, the binding between the old associated item can be removed and a new binding to the new item established.

To perform some action on a state change, if it relates to the toggle button, you can add a listener to the toggle button's value property or use a binding.  In the example, I use a binding on the value property and update the text of the toggle button based on the current value.

There is also a property representing the state in the model class. If needed, you can add listeners to the model class toggle state property, then you can be notified of state changes independent of the UI and toggle button.  For instance, you could write:

```
person.toggleStateProperty().addListener(
    (observable, oldValue newValue) -> {
        /** perform some action */
});
```

You can also use an [extractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31687642/callback-and-extractors-for-javafx-observablelist) defined on the list of items backing the table view to be notified when the toggle state of any item in the list changes.

In my full example code in this answer, to keep the example relatively simple, I don't add listeners or extractors to the model properties.

#### Full Example Code

*ComboTableApp.java*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.List;

public class ComboTableApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Person("Jacob", "Williams"),
                new Person("Isabella", "Carlisle"),
                new Person("Ethan", "Adura")
        );

        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(
                item -> item.getValue().firstNameProperty()
        );

        TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(
                item -> item.getValue().lastNameProperty()
        );

        TableColumn<Person, Person> toggleColumn = new TableColumn<>("Toggle");
        toggleColumn.setCellValueFactory(
                item -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(item.getValue())
        );
        toggleColumn.setCellFactory(
                p -> new ToggleTableCell()
        );

        final TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(
                List.of(
                        firstNameColumn, lastNameColumn, toggleColumn
                )
        );
        table.setPrefHeight(150);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(table));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

*Person.java*

```
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Person {
    private final StringProperty firstName;
    private final StringProperty lastName;
    private final BooleanProperty toggleState;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lastName);
        this.toggleState = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    }

    public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public BooleanProperty toggleStateProperty() {
        return toggleState;
    }
}
```

*ToggleTableCell.java*

```
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;

public class ToggleTableCell extends TableCell<Person, Person> {
    private final ToggleButton toggleButton = new ToggleButton();
    private BooleanProperty boundProperty;

    public ToggleTableCell() {
        toggleButton.textProperty().bind(
                Bindings.when(
                                toggleButton.selectedProperty()
                        )
                        .then("Selected")
                        .otherwise("Unselected")
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Person person, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(person, empty);

        if (person == null || empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
            if (boundProperty != null) {
                toggleButton.selectedProperty().unbindBidirectional(boundProperty);
                boundProperty = null;
            }
            return;
        }

        setGraphic(toggleButton);

        if (boundProperty != person.toggleStateProperty()) {
            if (boundProperty != null) {
                toggleButton.selectedProperty().unbindBidirectional(boundProperty);
            }

            boundProperty = person.toggleStateProperty();
            toggleButton.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(boundProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Generic Solution

A recommended generic solution would be an implementation based on modifications to a copy of the code of [CheckBoxTableCell](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTableCell.java).  That is an implementation that I won't present here, but the approach is similar to that described here, just a bit more generic so it can be used with any model class rather than a specific one as I use here.

#### Maintaining state for UI controls in `TableView`

If implementing similar functionality yourself, be careful about trying to copy a [tutorial for a simple button](https://riptutorial.com/javafx/example/27946/add-button-to-tableview) (as you noted in comments).  Such an approach may lead you down an incorrect path.

A button has no internal state that it reflects, whereas a toggle button does have a state (it can be selected or not).

As the items backing the rows get updated (e.g. new items added to the list, or the list is reordered, or the table sorted), you need the toggle button to continue to reflect the correct state for the item it was associated with (or the new item it is now associated with), but that is unnecessary for a simple button that has no state.

So the nature of the problem that needs to be solved when a stateful control such as a ToggleButton is involved is different than that for a stateless control and the solution may differ accordingly.  As such, when the UI controls in a TableView maintain state, it can become necessary to adopt some techniques similar to those demonstrated in this answer.